# How to cancel async task of long running process in Hub from blazor component with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

> In blazor class I am calling hub async method with cancellation token on button click

```
tokensource = new CancellationTokenSource();
token = tokensource.Token;
await _hubConnection.SendAsync("MachineOperationOnServer", MachineID, cancellationToken:token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

> On Button click I am cancelling the CancellationTokenSource

```
tokensource.Cancel();
```

> In hub class the method is

```
public async Task MachineOperationOnServer(int machineID)
        {
            
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                int progressPer = 0;

                for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    progressPer = Convert.ToInt32(((decimal)i / 20) * 100);
                    await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ProgressOnClient", progressPer);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);                    
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Note: Hub class OnDisconnectedAsync method hit when async task completed, but I want to abort the task before completion

Comment: From your code ,I see you create a CancellationToken using the CancellationTokenSource to cancel operation . Where is OnDisconnectedAsync ?

Answer (score 2):

There are async methods, which provide a state machine and convenient callback convention within C# code...but what I'm going to suggest is an asynchronous request...where the server receives a request and returns a confirmation before the work for the request completes.

Create a class to hold your **Correlation**. This will be a reference to the long running task, a request id, and a task completion source that could be used to cancel the task.

When the client calls to start the long running task, the server creates a Correlation instance, assigns it a unique ID (I'd suggest Guid.NewGuid()), starts the task (passing it the id and the cancellation token) and then stores the correlation somewhere it can be found later: I'd recommend a Dictionary<Guid, Correlation>. The server then returns the id. This id is your request id (sometimes also called an opaque identifier if the client isn't supposed to do anything with it but use it blindly for future related calls).

Now your server process will need to remove itself from the dictionary when it is done running, and you'll need to add a new cancel method to the server hub so that the client can request a cancel. If the client requests a cancel, they have to pass the request id, and then the server can look up the correlation and cancel the task by calling cancel on the task completion source. After a cancel you should also remove the correlation from the dictionary.

Its more complicated if you need a return result, but I'll leave that one up to you to figure out. There are a lot of gotchas to this type of coding, and you'll also need to worry about thread safety around access to your dictionary.

Comment: I tried but the problem is OnDisconnectedAsync is calling after complete execution of loop

Comment: If you follow my answer, you still need to check the correlations cancelation token's state and use it during any async operations inside the server side long running task. Also, don't use thread.sleep, you need to await Task.Delay and pass in the cancellation token to that as well.

Comment: can you please share some sample code to understand your logic, thank you

Comment: I'm not very inclined to spend more time on your answer. I can see that you don't upvote other people on this site and you posted multiple answers to your own (other) question. I'm not going to get any points by spending 30 minutes giving you an answer =(